# Fluentd sql output plugin configuration not working for Snowflake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, fluentd

Plugin: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql

I tried with MySQL and it's working perfectly fine. But with snowflake, it's giving error:

> [error]: #0 Could not load the 'snowflake' Active Record adapter.
> Ensure that the adapter is spelled correctly in config/database.yml
> and that you've added the necessary adapter gem to your Gemfile.

It seems there's something wrong with the adapter/adapter name.
I'm using docker for fluentd.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM fluent/fluentd:v1.15.3-debian-1.0
USER root
RUN ["fluent-gem", "install", "fluent-plugin-sql"]
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install make && \
    apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
RUN ["fluent-gem", "install", "sequel-snowflake"]
USER fluent
```

Conf:

```
  <match>
    @type sql
    adapter snowflake
    host my_org.snowflakecomputing.com
    port 443
    database PROD
    username <username>
    password <password>
    <table>
      table <schema>.EVENTS_TEST
      column_mapping 'name:name,value:value,labels:labels,type:type'
    </table>
  </match>
```

I've also tried `adapter  :snowflake` as mentioned in https://github.com/Yesware/sequel-snowflake

Comment: According to https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql, "**Other adapters supported by ActiveRecord should work.**". Have you verified whether the support for Snowflake is available?

Comment: @Azeem I don't know much about the rails but from the source code [ https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters ] I guess it's not supported but for sqlserver I found https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter so thought if a workaround for snowflake is there too...

Comment: [ActiveRecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/main/activerecord): "**Learn more and read about the built-in support for MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite3.**"

Comment: ^^^ No mention of Snowflake in above docs.

Comment: @Azeem Thanks for responding. I understood, it doesn't exist by default but support for sqlserver is there as activerecord-sqlserver-adapter. so just want to know if there's any workaround to implement it for snowflake.